# It doesn’t send a message in a DM with 'discord.py'

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My code:

```
a = 1
b = 600

@client.command()
async def iponergoopelda(ctx):
   for line in range(a, b):
         with open("id users2.txt") as f:
            data = f.readlines()
            for line in data:
               user = await client.fetch_user(int(line.strip()))
               await user.send('hey')
               print('Отправлено')
```

This doesn’t a send message in a [DM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_message) because the error with a DM,

```
Ignoring exception in command iponergoopelda:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Никитос\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Никитос\Desktop\Nukebot.py", line 51, in iponergoopelda
    await user.send('hey https://discord.com/api/oauth2/authorize?client_id=815193692432367646&permissions=2214068032&scope=bot')
  File "C:\Users\Никитос\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\abc.py", line 883, in send
    channel = await self._get_channel()
  File "C:\Users\Никитос\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\user.py", line 697, in _get_channel
    ch = await self.create_dm()
  File "C:\Users\Никитос\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\user.py", line 725, in create_dm
    data = await state.http.start_private_message(self.id)
  File "C:\Users\Никитос\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 247, in request
    raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50007): Cannot send messages to this user

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Никитос\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 902, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Никитос\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 864, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Никитос\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50007): Cannot send messages to this user
```

In the document I have ids for people. I tried to get it to work with three ids, but with 200 ids it doesn’t work.

How can I do it? Maybe *try* and *except*?

Comment: The user simply has the dm's disabled, there's no way of sending the message then. You can put a try/except block

Comment: Yes, but i dont know how do it, i try but this dont work, can u help me?

Answer (score 1):

The user simply has the dm's disabled, and there isn't any way of sending the message then. You can put a try/except block:

```py
a = 1
b = 600
@client.command()
async def iponergoopelda(ctx):
   for line in range(a , b):
         with open("id users2.txt") as f:
            data = f.readlines()
            for line in data:
               user = await client.fetch_user(int(line.strip()))

               try:
                   await user.send('hey')
               except:
                   pass

               print('Отправлено')
```